# Free up memory used by bash script

Tags: linux, bash, memory, process

I have a bash script that loops through the results of `find` for a directory containing hundreds of subdirectories and thousands of files and runs a number of commands on each file, mostly `sed` and `grep`.

I understand that this obviously computationally intensive.  The problem I'm running into is that it uses a *ton* of memory which isn't freed up when the script is finished.  This script is running inside of cygwin.  Closing cygwin does not free up any memory, I need to reboot Windows to get it back.

Is there a command I can run (either in Windows or cygwin) to free up memory used by the script?

Comment: I'm no expert, but try `purge` in cygwin. Works in Linux.

Comment: @dangenet `purge`? What is it? There is no such utility in Debian repository. To clear FS cache on GNU/Linux you may use `# sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Comment: @dangenet Oh, [I found](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/purge.8.html). It’s tool from OS X, is not it?

Comment: cygwin doesn't recognize the command, dangenet is probably right about it being an OSX utility.

Comment: Assuming that you run the script as something like `bash ./script`, all memory should be given back to the system after the bash-process ends, except (a) cygwin/bash has serious bug or (b) not all subprocesses started are actually really gone. Which measure exactly are you using that lets you know your RAM is all taken and no longer recoverable by Windows?

Comment: Please show your script once.. Update your question with your script what you tried

Comment: Y'all are right, `purge` is an OS X specific thing. My bad.

Comment: @Harald: I'm running it as `./script.sh`.  Does it make a difference if I run it as `bash script.sh`?  I'm currently using CoreTemp to measure the amount of physical memory in use by percentage, but the Windows task manager performance tab aligns with its assessment of memory usage.

Comment: @Ashish: I've made a few changes to improve efficiency.  First, I've moved almost all of the `sed` calls to be within a control structure that determines whether those calls are actually necessary in each iteration.  Second, I added an optional argument to the script that accepts a hard limit on the number of iterations to permit before exiting the loop.  For cleaning up memory usage in Windows, I downloaded Sysinternals RamMap and ran every option in the "Empty" menu; it seems to free up a lot, so this is looking close to a solution, but I will have to experiment a bit more to be sure.

Comment: Update to my last comment: running the RamMap "Empty" procedures seems to free up about a 3rd of the memory used, so this is inching towards a solution, but not there yet.

Answer (score 3):

Modern operating systems tend to use RAM for two main purposes:

- Processes
- Filesystem cache

In GNU/Linux, most of the times, you see a LOT of ram used, but most of it is actually just filesystem cache, which is discarded when memory is needed for real applications, on the fly, without any problems.

Example: my laptop has 7868MB of RAM. In total 6284 megs are used, but only 2441 are used by real programs.

So, to answer your question:

1. I have no idea (I cant see your code) if there are processes being spawned and kept alive, investigate on this, if you're sure there is none, go ahead.
2. Lookup in Windows (your OS) which command is used to discard filesystem cache. **WARNING**: empyting filesystem cache will probably make your computer slow for a moment or two, since operating system will have to re-read some of its components and some executable files from hard disk. (is there a way to tell Windows not to cache filesystem syscalls coming from a certain user/process/etc ?)

Please not that despite I am trying to help, I could be totally missing the point (I have no way to see your code, I'm just guessing basing on "symptoms" you described).

### Hope it helps,

Snoopy